# Walk across/through/on the crosswalk?

Tags: american-english, expression-choice

What is the correct collocation here?
Do you walk ***across** the crosswalk*, ***through** the crosswalk*, or ***on** the crosswalk*? Or can you say ***cross** the crosswalk*?

Comment: One crosses the road in the crosswalk.

Comment: ... or crosses the road at the crosswalk.

Comment: You can certainly cross the crosswalk. Personally, I would say, "I used the crosswalk."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=through%20the%20crosswalk%2C%20at%20the%20crosswalk%2C%20in%20the%20crosswalk%2C%20on%20the%20crosswalk&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthrough%20the%20crosswalk%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cat%20the%20crosswalk%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20the%20crosswalk%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Con%20the%20crosswalk%3B%2Cc0) shows that *in* is the most common term, followed by *at*, *on*, and then *through*. In my experience, they're used in different contexts.

If you want to distinguish using the crosswalk from crossing elsewhere, you use *at*. For instance, when I was a child, we were admonished:

> Always cross the street at the light or a crosswalk.

If you want to refer to a location when some event occurs, you can use *in*:

> The car didn't stop, even though I was in the crosswalk.

*on* is used when referring to other things being on the pavement of the crosswalk.

> There are zebra stripes painted on the crosswalk.

*through* tends to be used when talking about cars or bicycles going over the crosswalk in the direction of street travel, not crossing the street.

> The car went through the crosswalk even though there were pedestrians in it.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you are emphasizing

- across - just that you are trying to get to the other side of the street
- through - gives the feeling of a tunnel, maybe if there was a lot of traffic
- on - you made certain where to walk, perhaps for legal reasons
- cross - perhaps your destination is close to the other side of the road?

Answer (score 1):

**The answer to your questions is an emphatic, "Yes."**

Substitute the word "bridge" for crosswalk in your examples. "Through" is awkward, but the other words are all valid and, more importantly, each word paints a different world.

[image]

What words best describe The Beatles in the famous picture, above? Use the word that forces your reader to imagine the world you are creating.

Comment: Well they certainly were not crossing a "crosswalk". We do not know anything in Britain about any such named thing. They are walking across a "pedestrian crossing", or a "zebra crossing". The one in Abbey Road, London NW8 9AY,  to be precise.